# Sync events to google calendar using a chrome extension javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension which synchronize events to the user's google calendar, for that first i made a simple application on webforms to sync my events to the user's google calendar it works fine but when i tried same code in chrome extension it doesn't work

My Webform application.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <script>
          var clientId = '449930567958-oa2q2r6nhohm0655k6jifr3fsql7jaiq.apps.googleusercontent.com';
          var apiKey = 'AIzaSyBfTov7EesDsAMoorZ1e-muX0lsR0kEMto';

          // enter the scope of current project (this API must be turned on in the Google console)

          var now = new Date();
          var today = now.toISOString();
          var twoHoursLater = new Date(now.getTime() + (2 * 1000 * 60 * 60));
          twoHoursLater = twoHoursLater.toISOString();

          var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

          // OAuth2 functions
          function handleClientLoad() {
              console.log('handleClientLoad call');
              gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
              window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 2);
          }

          function checkAuth() {
              console.log("authorizing");
              gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false }, handleAuthResult);

          }
          function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
              console.log("authorize method");
              console.log("authorize method " +authResult.client_id);
              if (authResult && !authResult.error) {

                  console.log("makeapicall");
                  window.setTimeout(makeApiCall, 5000);
              } else {                                                  // otherwise, show button
                  console.log("Not authorized " + authResult.error);
              }
          }
          // This is the resource we will pass while calling api function
          var resource = {
              "summary": "My Event",
              "start": {
                  "dateTime": today
              },
              "end": {
                  "dateTime": twoHoursLater
              },
              "description": "We are organizing events",
              "location": "US",

          };

          function makeApiCall() {
              console.log("Done authorize");
              gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () { // load the calendar api (version 3)


                  var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert
                  ({
                      'calendarId': 'abcd@gmail.com',
                      // calendar ID which id of Google Calendar where you are creating events. this can be copied from your Google Calendar user view.

                      "resource": resource  // above resource will be passed here
                  });
                  console.log("hekki");
                  // handle the response from our api call
                  request.execute(function (resp) {
                      console.log(resp);
                      if (resp.status == 'confirmed') {
                          alert('Synced');
                      } else {
                          alert('Not Synced');
                      }
                  });
              });
          }
    </script>
     <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome extension

```
Manifest.json
{
"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Details",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Details of all your events",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  }}
```

Added following two scripts in popup.html

sync.js contains all the code which i have in the first script in webform application

handleClientLoad is not calling when i write code for the chrome extension

Comment: Chrome extension uses Identity API to authenticate user. You can start by checking their [documentation and sample code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth).

Comment: But i need to insert events on google calendar, i checked this identity api but this is not what i want this is something else. When i run the code on localhost that i pasted above it gives me a popup to signin to account and insert event into the calendar that all i want to do in extension

Comment: You have to add the scope to use Calendar API, see the lower part of the [document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth#enable_people). Also try checking this [GitHub code sample](https://github.com/GoogleDeveloperExperts/chrome-extension-google-apis)

Comment: added but still not working!